# ¿Duda sobre funciones reutilizables declaradas con let y const?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Lo único en que se diferencian las siguientes funciones son  `const` y `let`:

```
const cambiarColor = (event) => {event.target.style.background = "#c1c1c1"}

let cambiarColor = (event) => {event.target.style.background = "#c1c1c1"}
```

¿Cual es la diferencia? ¿tiene alguna ventaja, lo uno del otro?

Por ejemplo puedo usarlos sin ningun inconveniente:

```
elemento.addEventListener("click",cambiarColor);
```

No importa si fue declarada con `const` o `let` igual funcionara; por eso me preguntaba si hay alguna práctica común por elegir una y no la otra.

**NOTA:** no me refiero a la parte de definición de var, `let` y `const`; sino al echo de hacer reutilizable una función con `let` o `const`; ¿ustedes cuál eligen?

Comment: En realidad `let` se usa como alternativa a `var`. El primero sirve para declarar variables locales y el segundo para variables globales. En cuanto al `const`, no estoy seguro pero creo que define una constante o variable que no sé puede reasignar.

Comment: No conozco documentación que fundamente lo que voy a decir. Pero sé que la convención que se utiliza al declarar funciones en JavaSctipt es utilizar `const`. Supongo que será porque las funciones normalmente no se redefinen, solo se utilizan. De todas formas, en la práctica es completamente indistinto usar uno u otro, ya que ambas formas son validas. Recuerda que JavaScript no es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado, por lo que es habitual declarar objetos sin preocuparse por su tipo.

Comment: Un profesor me comento esto:   Porque es práctica común hacer esto en js moderno, hay una diferencia conceptual entre let y const, const es para algo que no se va a reasignar, let es para algo que se reasigna por ejemplo un for loop, let i =0.  creo que no hay diferencias; pero creo que elegiré "const" para hacer mis funciones reutilizables...

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con " funciones reutilizables"? No veo porqué elegir entre usar `const` o `let` favorecería más o menos a la reutilización de una función. Yo pienso que poder reutilizar una función depende de otros factores.

Comment: Exacto, no parece que ```const``` o ```let``` favorezcan la reutilización; pero alguno tendrás que usar... ¿Cuál? ¿Alguna convención?, o ¿es indistinto?

Comment: Claro. Como te mencioné en el comentario anterior, la convención es utilizar `const`. Pero si tu objetivo es hacer funciones reutilizables, yo me preocuparía más por otros factores como la clase de parámetros que declaras en la función, por ejemplo. Aunque en realidad cada función es distinta, y saber qué hacer para que sea reutilizable varía en cada caso.

Comment: Lo que me interesa es ajustarme al entorno de desarrollo y saber las convenciones; y las prácticas recomendadas... ¡Gracias por comentar a todos!!! Usaré la única respuesta para serrar la pregunta.

Comment: @kraud, te recomiendo revisar [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/515237/54039), no es de lo mismo, pero sí está relacionada y creo que puede serte muy útil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy sencillo.

Con el `let` puedes **redefinir** el objeto cuantas veces desees.

Por el otro lado, `const` es una **constante**, es decir que no se puede redenifir otra vez.

Fijate los siguientes ejemplos.

Esto sucede al intentar redefinir un `const`:

```js
const cambiarColorWithConst = (event) => {event.target.style.background = "#c1c1c1"}

cambiarColorWithConst = "new value"

console.log(cambiarColorWithConst)
```

Mientras que si intentas redefinir un `let`...

```js
let cambiarColorWithLet = (event) => {event.target.style.background = "#c1c1c1"}

cambiarColorWithLet = "new value"

console.log(cambiarColorWithLet)
```

Hay mucha más información en internet si quieres una explicación más extensa.

Sería solo cuestión de investigarlo.

**Actualización:**

Como veo que actualizaste tu pregunta agregaré algunos detalles más a mi respuesta.

No conozco documentación que fundamente lo que voy a decir. Pero sé que la convención que se utiliza al declarar funciones en JavaScript es utilizar `const`.

Supongo que será porque las funciones normalmente no se redefinen, solo se utilizan.

Pero en la práctica es completamente indistinto usar uno u otro, ya que ambas formas son validas. Recuerda que JavaScript no es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado, por lo que es habitual declarar objetos sin preocuparse por su tipo.

De todas formas, eso no influirá en si tu función será reutilizable o no. Eso depende de muchos factores y varía en cada caso.

Comment: Sé que const no se puede redefinir, además siempre debe ser inicializada; y que "let" se puede redefinir además no necesita ser inicializada.  Mi pregunta iba por la parte semántica al ser funciones reutilizables no afecta en nada a su uso que sea "const" o "let", así parece...

Comment: Ah. No habías aclarado ese punto originalmente en tu pregunta. Así que creí que era una pregunta sobre fundamentos de JavaScript. En ese caso esta respuesta no te va a aportar una solución definitiva a la nueva versión de tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, sorry; gracias por responder igual...

Comment: Ok, no hay problema. De todas formas le agregué un par de detalles más para que encaje con tu actualización.